# How to distinguish Outermost Accordion vs nested Accordions click event using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/UD5eY/2/

which shows two Accordions on start up namely **Students** and **Employees** 
and these Accordions can have nested Accordions .

Is it possible to get an alert (`click event fired` ) when clicked on Students or Employees (I mean for outermost Accordions only)
because I have a seperate logic when nested Accordion is clicked and seperate logic when the outermost Accordion is clicked.

I have used

which is actually getting fired up for all Accordions including nested also .

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({
    activate: function (event, ui) {
        setStuff(event, ui);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest thing I could think of off the top of my head would be to just add a class to your outer most accordion, and then listen to the click event of those.

Try something like this. http://jsfiddle.net/UD5eY/3/

**HTML**

```
<h3><a href="#" class="Outer">Students </a></h3>
<div id="inner"></div>

<h3><a href="#" class="Outer">Employees </a></h3>
<div id="inner"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".Outer").parent().click(function() {
    //do codez!
    alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: Working very fine without disturbing existing functionality , thanks once again .

Comment: is it possible to get the clciked Accordian name in that function ??

Comment: when i clciked its giving undefined